# how to make raylib projects work in VS Code?

Tags: visual-c++

i recently installed raylib, i got a problem, my normal cpp files compile with no errors, but when i want to compile raylib test project it pops me these errors:

- Executing task: C:\raylib\w64devkit\bin\gcc.exe -Wall -Wextra -g3 c:\Users\Windows\Downloads\C++\VS Raylib\main.c -o c:\Users\Windows\Downloads\C++\VS Raylib\output\main.exe

C:\raylib\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Temp\ccA7elgC.o: in function `main': c:/Users/Windows/Downloads/C++/VS Raylib/main.c:49: undefined reference to` InitWindow'
C:\raylib\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: c:/Users/Windows/Downloads/C++/VS Raylib/main.c:62: undefined reference to `SetTargetFPS' C:\raylib\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: c:/Users/Windows/Downloads/C++/VS Raylib/main.c:66: undefined reference to` WindowShouldClose'
C:\raylib\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Temp\ccA7elgC.o: in function `UpdateDrawFrame': c:/Users/Windows/Downloads/C++/VS Raylib/main.c:85: undefined reference to` UpdateCamera'
C:\raylib\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: c:/Users/Windows/Downloads/C++/VS Raylib/main.c:90: undefined reference to `BeginDrawing' C:\raylib\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: c:/Users/Windows/Downloads/C++/VS Raylib/main.c:92: undefined reference to` ClearBackground'
C:\raylib\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: c:/Users/Windows/Downloads/C++/VS Raylib/main.c:94: undefined reference to `BeginMode3D' C:\raylib\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: c:/Users/Windows/Downloads/C++/VS Raylib/main.c:96: undefined reference to` DrawCube'
C:\raylib\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: c:/Users/Windows/Downloads/C++/VS Raylib/main.c:97: undefined reference to `DrawCubeWires' C:\raylib\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: c:/Users/Windows/Downloads/C++/VS Raylib/main.c:98: undefined reference to` DrawGrid'
C:\raylib\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: c:/Users/Windows/Downloads/C++/VS Raylib/main.c:100: undefined reference to `EndMode3D' C:\raylib\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: c:/Users/Windows/Downloads/C++/VS Raylib/main.c:102: undefined reference to` DrawText'
C:\raylib\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: c:/Users/Windows/Downloads/C++/VS Raylib/main.c:104: undefined reference to `DrawFPS' C:\raylib\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: c:/Users/Windows/Downloads/C++/VS Raylib/main.c:106: undefined reference to` EndDrawing'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

- The terminal process "C:\raylib\w64devkit\bin\gcc.exe '-Wall', '-Wextra', '-g3', 'c:\Users\Windows\Downloads\C++\VS Raylib\main.c', '-o', 'c:\Users\Windows\Downloads\C++\VS Raylib\output\main.exe'" terminated with exit code: 1.
- Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

Here is the code:

````
#include "raylib.h"

#if defined(PLATFORM_WEB)
    #include <emscripten/emscripten.h>
#endif

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Local Variables Definition (local to this module)
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Camera camera = { 0 };
Vector3 cubePosition = { 0 };

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Local Functions Declaration
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
static void UpdateDrawFrame(void);          // Update and draw one frame

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Main entry point
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    // Initialization
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    const int screenWidth = 800;
    const int screenHeight = 450;

    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "raylib");

    camera.position = (Vector3){ 10.0f, 10.0f, 8.0f };
    camera.target = (Vector3){ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
    camera.up = (Vector3){ 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
    camera.fovy = 60.0f;
    camera.projection = CAMERA_PERSPECTIVE;

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#if defined(PLATFORM_WEB)
    emscripten_set_main_loop(UpdateDrawFrame, 60, 1);
#else
    SetTargetFPS(60);               // Set our game to run at 60 frames-per-second
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Main game loop
    while (!WindowShouldClose())    // Detect window close button or ESC key
    {
        UpdateDrawFrame();
    }
#endif

    // De-Initialization
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CloseWindow();                  // Close window and OpenGL context
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    return 0;
}

// Update and draw game frame
static void UpdateDrawFrame(void)
{
    // Update
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    UpdateCamera(&camera, CAMERA_ORBITAL);
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Draw
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    BeginDrawing();

        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);

        BeginMode3D(camera);

            DrawCube(cubePosition, 2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, RED);
            DrawCubeWires(cubePosition, 2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, MAROON);
            DrawGrid(10, 1.0f);

        EndMode3D();

        DrawText("This is a raylib example", 10, 40, 20, DARKGRAY);

        DrawFPS(10, 10);

    EndDrawing();
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
} ```

at first it didnt read mingw32-make, so i added a path, it made compiling normal files work, but not those that use raylib.
````